# In what scenarios should we select maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, build, setup-project

Well I have learned a lot about advantages and disadvantages of Maven.

This question is very specific

- In what scenarios should we select maven?

like

- Huge changing dependencies?
- Automate build process? Do we need maven why not hudson?

**Need answers to help me find out in understanding that at a start of project few things that I must look into to know whether I need maven.**

I just don't want to use maven just because all are using it, I want a strong reason that in such and such conditions maven is the only best solution available.

Comment: Can't think of any reason *not* to use Maven.

Comment: Slow? Forces your project into a specific template? Downloads the internets!? ;)

Comment: @adarshr : There are so many reasons but I am taking about situations so no reason to down vote

Comment: @AmolGhotankar I didn't. Now I might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One area where in I faced challenges in past is : When your application needs a custom archive. This generally happens when you have an application wherein the generated artifacts are not standard (jar,war,ear). There the assembly plugin was the way out. But again, we were missed the ease with the Ant lets us do that.

To answer your question,

- In what scenarios should we select maven? (dependencies, automated build)

Maven is works like a magic wand for resolving dependencies and specially the [transitive dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) which are not easily  resolvable when you use ants. Automated builds (you mentioned hudoson) use the tools like Ants or Maven. If you need automated tool, you simply need it.  The tool will anyways need either or Ants or Maven

Don't see Maven as a build tool only. Building is just one of the aspects. Maven plays role during all the stages of life cycle of a project.

Answer (score 3):

Maven is weakest when

- the default lifecycle doesn't meet your needs (most common case: when you need more than 2 test phases)
- you want scripting abilities in your build

Downloading the Internet is a problem, but I'd rather deal with that problem than go back to manual dependency management.  I would only replace Maven with something that handled dependencies at least equally well.

Here are a couple of links for further reading:

[3-part criticism on DZone](http://java.dzone.com/news/maven-great-idea-poor) - see also the comments

[Another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385401/maven-replacement)